# Pay via PayPal step 6 (Order Review) is being skipping

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, paypal, review

On Magento ver. 1.9.1.0 using the default checkout, when a user selects to pay via PayPal step 6  (Order Review) is being skipping, but this step is essential to me as it has order comments. How can I make sure the user sees this step when selecting to pay via paypal?

Answer (score 2):

By design the user leaves the site for PayPal Express after step 5.  They return to a separate order confirmation page.  You would need to add your comments module to that final page (/paypal/express/review).

Alternatively you can use the old style PayPal Payments Standard where the user completed order at step 6 and then proceeds to pay.  I think this method is being deprecated though.

Comment: Good points, and, indeed, with version 1.9.1.1 it seems we are deprived of this final step when people choose PayPal as a payment method. It would be really cool if we could offer the customer a final order summary before going to PayPal.